# How do I do "buy 3 and pay 2" math?

Tags: php, math, e-commerce, shopping-cart, percentage

I have a shopping cart and I need to build the offer function, I have already completed the percentage off and I need some help with quantity promotions.

For example, if the customer buys 3 items he pays only for 2 but if he wants to buy 5 items I must apply for the promotion only for 3 items and 2 are at full price.

Here it's my code

```
    $quand_in_cart =  '5'; //quantity for product X in the cart
    $prod_price = '1.5'; //product price

    $percentage_off = NULL;
    $buy_any = 3; //promotion on 3 items
    $for_the_price = 2; //pay only 2

    if($percentage_off and $quand_in_cart >= $buy_any){

        $price_discount = ($percentage_off/100) * $quand_in_cart; //works percentage done.

    } elseif ($buy_any && $for_the_price) {
        if($quand_in_cart >= $buy_any){
            //here i need some help
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start with the highest quantity check first: `if(quantity >= 5){} else if (quantity >= 3)...`

Comment: `$fullPrice = $quand_in_cart % $buy_any; $discounted = $quand_in_cart - $fullPrice;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

buy 3 and pay 2 with Rest X with full price.

In mathamatics it means:

```
items_to_pay = floor(amount / 3) * 2 + X, with X = amount mod 3
```

So in your code:

```
$price = $prod_price * ((floor($quand_in_cart / $buy_any)*$for_the_price + ($quand_in_cart % $buy_any))
```

EDIT: **some more explanations**

```
floor($quand_in_cart / $buy_any)*$for_the_price // for every 3, only add 2 to the price
($quand_in_cart % $buy_any) // how many items are the rest if you devide by $buy_any
```

add this two values and you have the amount of items that have to be multiplied with the price for one item. That's it.